# How to deploy using the compute engine

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

**How to deploy using the compute engine**? I want to continually deploy through the bitbucket pipeline.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read
[what this site is about](https://stackoverflow.com/about) and 
"[How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)" 
before asking a question.

Answer (score 0):

You can mirror a Bitbucket repository into GCP following the steps from this [article](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/mirroring-a-bitbucket-repository) , however you will need to [create a Bitbucket account](https://guides.co/g/bitbucket-101/11151) first.

I recommend you to edit your question and provide more details and what you are trying to achieve.